# Pandas summing up two rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I need to merge two rows.
Ex:

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Col1</th>
<th>Col2</th>
<th>Col3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>City1</td>
<td>Pop1</td>
<td>Area1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City2</td>
<td>Pop2</td>
<td>Area2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City1</td>
<td>Pop3</td>
<td>Area3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to merge City1 in one row and I am trying to add(sum) population and area
Expected result needs to be this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>City1</td>
      <td>Pop(1+3)</td>
      <td>Area(1+3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City2</td>
      <td>Pop2</td>
      <td>Area2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried different variations of
`df.groupby(['Col1']).aggregate({'Col2': "sum", 'Col3': "sum"})`

This merges the rows, but instead of summing up the values, it just writes them one next to each other, like this:  City1, Pop1Pop3, Area1Area3.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dtype of `Col2` and `Col3` to int or float. They are concatenated because they are seen as str (or objects)

Comment: I just tried that and I got another error as the number is 669,338. I tried to convert the string to a float but it gives an error. I think the issue is that  a comma is used as a separator instead of a dot. 669,338 instead of 669.338.

Comment: I managed to solve it, I replaced comma with dot and then converted them to int. Thank you!